# $n$ boys and $n$ girls go out to dance. How many ways so they all dance together (boys must dance with girls)?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

The problem is : $n$ boys and $n$ girls go out to dance. How many ways so they all dance simultaneously (only couples of different sex can dance together) ?

My thinking is we can look at it as $2n$ ordered slots
So lets say $n = 3$, then we have _ _ _ _ _ _

For the first slot, we can choose any of the $3$ boys, and for the second any of the $3$ girls. $3~3$ _ _ _ _

For the next $2$ slots, we have $2$ boys and girls respectively $3~3~2~2$ _ _

and finally $3~3~2~2~1~1$

That would give us $3 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 = 36$ arrangements or $3! \cdot 3!$.

If we take one example arrangement lets say $B_1G_1B_2G_2B_3G_3$, amongst the $36$ arrangements we will have counted it $3!=6$ times since $B_1G_1B_2G_2B_3G_3 =  B_2G_2B_1G_1B_3G_3$ etc... So we divide by $3!$ to get $6$.

My questions:

1. Is this a valid argument for why the general form answer is $n!$ ?
2. What other ways to reason about this problem are there?

Comment: 1. Because they are not dancing in a line. Start with a random boy. He needs a girl to dance with. There are $n$ to choose. Pick a second random boy (different from the first). There are $n-1$ choices for the girl to pair him with. Keep going until all pairs are formed. Alternately you can start with a girl and choose a random boy.

Comment: Your approach is like letting boys and girls choose their dancing partners simulatniously and then eliminating the douplicate choices.I would recommend not to let boys and girls choose simultaniously (this might end up in a fight), but in the first place either the boys or the girls chose.

Answer (score 3):

1st boy has $n$ possibilities for choosing a girl, then

2nd boy has $n-1$ possibilities for choosing a girl, then

...

nth boy has just 1 girl left to dance with.

Seemingly there are $n (n-1) (n-2) ... 1 = n!$ possible combinations.

Answer (score 2):

You gave a valid argument for the case $n = 3$.

For the general case, we can line up the boys in $n!$ ways and the girls in $n!$ ways, then match the $k$th boy in the boys' line with the $k$th girl in the girls' line to form $n$ couples.  This gives $n!n!$ ways of selecting the couples.  However, we have counted the same set of couples $n!$ ways, once for each way we could have lined up the same $n$ couples (or, equivalently, the number of ways we could have lined up the girls).  Therefore, the number of ways the dance partners can be selected is 
$$\frac{n!n!}{n!} = n!$$

Here is a simplified version of your argument:  Line up the girls in some order, say alphabetically.  There are $n!$ ways of lining up the boys.  Match the $k$th girl in the line with the $k$th boy in the line to determine the dance partners.  Hence, there are $n!$ ways to form the dance partners.

By fixing the order of the girls, we eliminate the need to divide by the $n!$ orders in which the same $n$ couples could be formed.